# How to getElementByID, but only part of it?

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vbscript, getelementbyid

I use getElementByID to transfer data from IE to Excel, but how to get only part of it if fx the innerText includes number and text and only number is needed, or if the interesting part is written in red color and the rest in black? Would you specify it by class or type, and if so, how?

```
ws.Range("A1").Value = objExplorer.document.getElementByID("the ID of the element which includes unwanted characters").innerText
```

Comment: Hi, can you post an example of the HTML you are trying to parse?

Comment: On this site: http://www.trafficestimate.com/www.abbott.com I would like to just get the number 479,600 and avoid/remove the rest: <div id="ctl00_cphMainContent_ucGoogleMonthlyChart_pnlEstimateOnly">
  
    <br />
    <div class="chart-yoy">
        <span style="color: Green;">Www.abbott.com has received an estimated <span style="color: red;">479,600</span> visits over the last 30 days.</span>
    </div>

Comment: Try running just the code I posted, nothing else. Delete everything else. Make sure you have the page open before running, let me know what you get.

Comment: I get these two errors to begin with: Line 2, 13, expected end of statement, 800A0401. Line 13, 56, expected end of statement, 800A0401. Does it work at your end? I cannot see where the destination excel is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Replace(), Substitute(), Left(), Right() if in case the TEXT characters length is always same...***example ABC123, CCC3456, DGF453454***

If TEXT characters length are not same then use following VB code to create UDF(user defined formula):

```
Public Function removeLetters(ByVal str As String) As String
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .ignorecase = True
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[a-z]"
        removeLetters = .Replace(str, "")
    End With
End Function
```

And use it as below:

```
ws.Range("A1").Value = removeLetters(objExplorer.document.getElementByID("the ID of the element which includes unwanted characters").innerText)
```

**Modify above code accordingly

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will grab the text based on it's color based on the Style.Color property. I'm using a UDF FindWindow to get a pointer to an existing webpage.

```
Public Sub FindRedOrGreenText()
    Dim ie          As Object
    Dim Element     As Object
    Dim Elements    As Object

    Set ie = FindWindow("URL", "trafficestimate.com")

    If Not ie Is Nothing Then
        Set Elements = ie.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_cphMainContent_ucGoogleMonthlyChart_pnlEstimateOnly").getelementsbyTagName("span")

        For Each Element In Elements
            If Element.Style.Color = "green" Then
                Debug.Print "Here is the green text! "; Element.innertext
            ElseIf Element.Style.Color = "red" Then
                Debug.Print "Here is the red text! "; Element.innertext
            End If
        Next Element
    End If

    Set Element = Nothing
    Set Elements = Nothing
    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub

Function FindWindow(SearchBy As String, SearchCriteria As String) As Object
    Dim Window      As Object

    For Each Window In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        If SearchBy = "URL" And Window.LocationUrl Like "*" & SearchCriteria & "*" Then
            Set FindWindow = Window
            Exit Function
        ElseIf SearchBy = "Name" And Window.LocationName Like "*" & SearchCriteria & "*" Then
            Set FindWindow = Window
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Window

    Set FindWindow = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, this might indeed be exactly what I need. However, I am having troubleusing the script. Would you be able to take a quick look at what I have above?

Comment: What trouble are you having? Specific error? What do the debug.print statements say?

Comment: It gives an error regarding line 37, char 54, Expected end of statement, 800A0401. This is the part with For Each Element in Elements. Perhaps I have simply put it wrong together with the existing script, but not sure.

Comment: I just noticed you are writing this with VBScript, sorry I missed this. the solution above is in VBA...is it a requirement to write this in VBScript?

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're probably looking for is a regular expression. If you want just the number value of the inner text then you could use

```
objExplorer.document.getElementByID("id").innerText.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
```

Comment: That's not VBScript.

Comment: Pretty sure [`Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954(v=vs.84).aspx) in VBScript doesn't support Regular Expressions.